# What does "wd" mean?

Tags: emacs, background-process

What does "wd" mean in the following output of an emacs background job?

```
$jobs
[3]-  Stopped emacs -nw new\ file  (wd: ~/dirlinks/cs/computer_system/composition/hardware)
```

Answer (score 9):

“Working Directory” (i.e., the second and third letters of `pwd`). 
This reminds you of the directory that the background job was started in,
in case you have `cd`’ed elsewhere in the shell.

Comment: is it only shown in output of "jobs"?

Comment: It can also appear when you type fg to re-enter the job, to remind you of the same.

Answer (score 0):

A **command terminal** always has an associated **Working Directory** → **wd**, which is the **directory in which commands are executed**.

```
$ ls ## list the working directory file of "wd → working directory"

$ ls dir1 ## directory files list dir1, contained in wd

$ ls ../dir2 ## directory files list dir2, contained in the parent directory of wd

$ ls /home/user1/dir3 ## list of files identified by the absolute path dir3

$ nano file.ext ## edit, if exist, or create, if not exist, the file.ext of the working directory

$ pwd ## shows the absolute path to the working directory of the command terminal 

$ cd dir1 ## changes the working directory by the directory 'dir1' contained in it

$ cd .. ## changes the working directory to its parent directory (the first on the path to the root)
```

The **UNIX/LINUX** file and directory system has a **tree structure** and the files are in commands with **absolute paths**, which start in the **root directory** of the tree (identified with **/**), or **relative**, starting at **wd** (working directory)

**Routes** are **paths** in the **directory tree**.

```
dir1 
.. /dir2
```

Are routes **relative** to wd

While

```
/home/user1/dir3
```

It is an **absolute path** that part of the **root directory** that identifies the **dir3** directory

Content in the **user1** directory

**user1** in turn is contained in the **home directory**, which is
contained in the **root directory → /**